# Updating Graph from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-graphview

I'm developing an app where users can enter their blood glucose levels and have them displayed in a graph. For this project i'm using tabbed navigation with the graph being on Tab1 and the input being on Tab2.

I want to make it so that when the user adds data on Tab2 the graph auto updates on Tab1. I would make the graph update using the onStart(); function but I can't because Fragments won't close/reopen unless I go to Tab3 in my tabbed navigation due to android saving the last 2 open fragments.

**Tab1**

```
public class tab1 extends Fragment {

DatabaseHelper myDb;
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
GraphView graph;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    initControls();
    initGraph();

}




private void initControls() {

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    sqLiteDatabase = myDb.getReadableDatabase();

}
public void initGraph() {
    graph = getView().findViewById(R.id.graph);

    series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(getData());
    graph.addSeries(series);


    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);

    graph.getViewport().setScrollable(true);
    graph.getViewport().setScalable(true);
}

public void showMessage(String title, String Message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}


public DataPoint[] getData() {
    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();

    DataPoint[] dp = new DataPoint[res.getCount()];

    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        showMessage("Error", "Nothing Found");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < res.getCount(); i++) {
        res.moveToNext();
        dp[i] = new DataPoint(res.getInt(0), res.getFloat(1));
    }

    return dp;
}
}
```

**Tab 2**

```
public class tab2 extends Fragment {

DatabaseHelper myDb;
private tab1 tb1 = new tab1();
EditText editText_Glucose;
Button btn_Add;

//Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

}

public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    initControls();
}

private void initControls() {
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    editText_Glucose = getView().findViewById(R.id.editText_Glucose);
    btn_Add = getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_Add);

    AddData();

}

public void AddData() {
    btn_Add.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editText_Glucose.getText().toString());
                        if (isInserted)
                            showToast(getActivity(), "Data Inserted");
                        else
                            showToast(getActivity(), "Data not Inserted");
                }
            }
    );
}

public static void showToast(Context mContext, String message){
    Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Or maybe use local(!) broadcasts, or an Event Bus

Comment: Did you try overriding onResume() ? This will be caleld each time you return to the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) for this ?

To do so, add this in your main layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Then in your activity or fragment's onViewCreated():

```
    /* ... */
    mTabs = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
    Tab tab1 = mTabs.newTab();
    Tab tab2 = mTabs.newTab();

    mTabs.addTab(tab1 , true);
    mTabs.addTab(tab2 , false);
   /* ... */
```

You can check out this tutorial for more details about TabLayout:
http://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/tablayout-example-android-studio.html

Comment: thanks for your reply i'm not sure where to add these lines of code could you be more specific?

Comment: Please check out the link I've added in my answer. You can adapt the tutorial project to your need by using your tab1 and tab2 fragment classes as FirstFragment and SecondFragment classes